# 1004 Error code when removing pictures with For Each from Excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I made a VBA based form that tracks details about a complaint.

I added a feature to add a picture to the report/form.

When the form is submitted the filled cells are copied to a separate spreadsheet. The form needs to wiped and the pictures removed so that a new report can be filled if necessary. It is like a reset.

To remove the pictures I copied the below piece of script. About 90% of the time the images are removed and the form is back to it's original state.

Every once in a while I get

> Error 1004 "Application Defined or Object Defined Error".

I am unable to remove the pictures and need to restart the Excel file.

Within the editor, highlighted in yellow

```
k.TopLeftCell
```

```vb
With Sheets("Klachtformulier")
    Dim k As Shape, rng As Range
    Set rng = Sheets("Klachtformulier").Range("A43:H47")
    For Each k In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If Intersect(k.TopLeftCell, rng) Is Nothing Then
        Else
            k.Delete
        End If
    Next k
```

I tried to change `ActiveSheet` to the `sheet("name")`, tried to change the range, tried to change shape dim into a picture dim and tried to exit the for after one loop. Most of the time these changes cause the pictures to not be removed anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is likely that you are deleting members of a collection (the Shapes collection) while iterating over it using 'For ... Each'. When deleting, you should use 'For ... Next' and loop from the end of the collection to the start:

```
Dim k As Shape, rng As Range
Dim i As Long
Set rng = Sheets("Klachtformulier").Range("A43:H47")
For i = ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
  Set k = ActiveSheet.Shapes.Item(i)
  If Not Intersect(k.TopLeftCell, rng) Is Nothing Then
        k.Delete
    End If
Next i
```

I tweaked the logic of your `If` statement and removed the `With` line as (in the code you posted) it isn't doing anything useful.

Comment: So far the picture delete function seems to work just as fine. I haven't encountered the error yet so hopefully this solved it. Thank you a lot!